# Rails 3 - sortable list not working together with wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using sortable list like described here: http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery/

application.html.erb is looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js", "rails.js" %>

      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
   </head>
 <body>
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
   <div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>

  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>
<%= yield :javascript %>
</body>
</html>
```

The google apis are needed for the sortable list, but if I use those no other javascript is working, in my case the wysihtml5-editor. It works if I delete the google-api, but then the lists are not sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had imported query twice, one time over the asset pipeline with the "jquery-rails" gem, one time via the javascript_include_tag. What I missed to import via the asset pipeline was query-ui. After that I could remove the javascript_include_tag. Stupid me!